# Grant read_page_mailboxes to app/token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is probably a very noob question, but I've wasted the last day over it, so here goes:

Using Facebook's Graph API, I want my app's server to be able to retrieve all conversations from my page.  As per the docs, I should be able to do so by calling

```
GET /<MY_PAGE_ID>/conversations?access_token=<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

However, I get an error

```
(#279) Requires read_page_mailboxes permission to manage the object
```

Which makes sense, since I never granted the read_page_mailbox permission.
However, I can't find a way (either through the API or the developer management interface) to grant it.  How on Earth can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: i can see the read_page_mailboxes permission in the api explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer - just ask for it in your login process.

Comment: As @luschn already wrote, you need an access token with that permission. Somehow your application gets an access token and in that process you simply need to add the permission. Afterwards you need the page access token to work with the page mailbox. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens